# set contact's photo to null causes skia

Tags: android, android-emulator

anybody knows how to set contacts photo to default(no picture) from code?
when i update the database and set Photo.PHOTO to null , and then when i open contacts , the emulator starts giving

DEBUG/skia(1298): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null     forever.
Why?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Tin You need to go through your previous questions and mark the best answer as the "correct" answer.

Comment: Thank you but I haven't any answer for previous question... I'll do that as soon as I have one